# Kubernetes Daemonset on all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

If each node in a Kubernetes cluster is running a pod for the daemonset, is it possible to have that daemonset available in multiple namespaces without creating a separate pod per node per namespace?

For example I want to run a proxy server that is available in multiple namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are no **official** kubernetes controllers with the ability to share resources across namespaces (you can find un-namespaced objects).

but, I bold the word "official", because this is a typical project for custom operators/controllers, and probably you can find someone that builds this kind of controller.

Comment: Interesting. What do you think about running the proxy daemonset in one namespace but making its port reachable from any namespace. At the end of the day what I care about is that the proxy server's port can be reached out from any namespace.

Comment: you didn't clarify your needs, but yes, this is one of the purposes of daemonsets

Comment: I was gonna use Google Cloud SQL Proxy as daemonset to reduce the overhead of running it as sidecard. I decided to move back to the sidecard pattern due to security reasons.